# For what values of $(k, c)$, $\frac{8k-2c+n}{4n}$ is even?

Tags: number-theory

Let $n\in\{4, 6, 8, ...\}, k\in\{0, 1, ..., n-1\}, c\in\{0, 1, ..., [n/2]\}$. Then I want to know - for a given $n$, a rule/formula for the order pair $(k, c)$ for which $\frac{8k-2c+n}{4n}$ is even.

Comment: But your formula does not always generate  integers?

Comment: I need only integral solutions. For example, $(0, n/2)$ always works. Also, if $n$ is a multiple of 8, then $(7n/8, 0), (15n/8, 0), ...$ works. I need all such pairs for a given $n$. Now is it possible?

Comment: The issue is that when you're trying to characterize divisibility problem, for example when you're saying that $n$ is even this means that you'r saying that $n$ is divisible by $2$. for example your number is even if and only if $8k-2c+n$ is divisible by $8n$ which is the same thing, otherwise you can do the "dual problem" by first choosing $n$ and choosing your number $d$ and then find the integers $k,c$

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But again whether the 'dual problem' has a generalized solution?